# pgAdmin 4 and postgreSQL 10 on Windows: Issue with setting attribute check constraints

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, postgresql-10

I am using pgAdmin 4 along with postgreSQL 10 on Windows 10 and am trying to set some check constraints on one or more attributes of my table called 'parcels2007'. When I right click on 'parcels2007' and go to 'properties', I am seeing a constraints tab and then a 'Check' sub-tab. I clicked on it (see screenshot below).

[image]

and create a new check constraints based on attribute '**schdist**' being within a list of pre-specified values. However, after I click 'Save' and open the first 100 rows and try to edit the 'schdist' attribute with something wrong, it does NOT throw any error (like it should instead) and it lets me change the field without issues.

[image]

Could you please help me understand what I might be doing wrong here and what else I could try?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are talking about dialog save button or the save button on the toolbar?
- Query tool will do not validate any constraint by itself but once you click on Save button from toolbar Postgres should throw an error.

Ref: https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/3.x/editgrid.html
(Check: The View/Edit Data Toolbar section)

Comment: That is the dialog box that opens when you double-click inside the table field you are trying to manually edit. It lets me edit the field and change its value after clicking Save without any error. I am not using the Query tool, if that is what you were asking. I simply set a constraint on the attribute and then manually try to change it...in pgAdmin III it used to throw an error right away when trying to modify the attribute...

Answer (score 0):

Use can use the **F6 button** to save your changes.

So after selecting the View Data/View All Rows press F6 to save changes.